# Accessing Form's Control from Custom Control

Tags: c#

I want to access the list box and add the item into it for my Custom control which is dynamically created on run time. I want to add the Item when I press the button place in the custom control, but it does not work. I have use the following code to work:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.ABC = "HI";
    }
```

the 'ABC' is the Public string on the form ie:

```
    public string ABC
    {
       set { listBox1.Items.Add (value); }
    }
```

the above string works fine when I use it form the Button on the form and it adds the value in the lsitbox but whent I use it form the custom control's button the text of the 'value' changes but it does not add the item in list box.I have also try it on tabel but does not help. I change the Modifires of the ListBox1 from Private to Public but it does not works. The above function works well in the form but cannot work from the custom control.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Expose an event ("ItemAdded" or whatever) in the child form that your main form can handle.  Pass the data to any event subscribers through an EventArgs derived object.  Now your mainform can update the UI as it please with no tight coupling between the two classes. One class should not know about the UI layout of another, it's a bad habit to get into (one that everyone seems to suggest when this question crops up).

Answer (score -1):

What I think you should use is

```
this.ParentForm
```

So in your case it should be:

```
public string ABC
{
   set { this.ParentForm.listBox1.Items.Add (value); }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way would be to pass the form down into your custom control as a parameter in the constructor that way you could access it from the custom control.

EX:

```
public class CustomControl
{
    private Form1 _form;

    public CustomControl(Form1 form)
    {
        _form = form;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       _form.ABC = "HI";
    }
}
```

Comment: Easy, yet crappy.  Events are the way to go.

Comment: Hi Tyler. When i use your method it shows me error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"